# How To AutoStart automatically without open setting in android programatically

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, bootcompleted

As I want to update the location to server in every two mins so I added service class in android, when mobile is restarted I'm calling broadcast receiver using boot_completed.But that receiver is not calling even when I  my device is restarted or I opened the application that time also I didn't get.

Because AUTO-START is disabled ,that's why its not coming.How to enable programatically in android like enabling gps popup same like that.

Code:If I give like that ,it opens the permission of auto start page, instead of showing manually how to enable it.Please help me. This code each time app open means coming even-though it is enabled.

```
if(Build.BRAND.equalsIgnoreCase("xiaomi") ){

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.miui.securitycenter", "com.miui.permcenter.autostart.AutoStartManagementActivity"));
    startActivity(intent);


}else if(Build.BRAND.equalsIgnoreCase("Letv")){

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.letv.android.letvsafe", "com.letv.android.letvsafe.AutobootManageActivity"));
    startActivity(intent);

}
else if(Build.BRAND.equalsIgnoreCase("Honor")){

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.huawei.systemmanager", "com.huawei.systemmanager.optimize.process.ProtectActivity"));
    startActivity(intent);

}

public class BootCompletedIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    PendingIntent pintent;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Toast.makeText(context, "boot"+intent.getAction(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.i("QQ","boot"+intent.getAction());

        if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Intent pushIntent = new Intent(context, ForegroundLocationService.class);
            context.startService(pushIntent);

/*
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
         intent = new Intent(context, ForegroundLocationService.class);
            pintent = PendingIntent
                    .getService(context, 0, intent, 0);
            Log.i("QQ","else--less than oreo"+pintent);

            AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)context. getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            // Start service every 20 seconds
            alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
                    5* 1000, pintent);*/
        }
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

 <receiver android:enabled="true"
        android:directBootAware="true"
        android:exported="true" android:name=".background_services.BootCompletedIntentReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="enable" android:value="true"/>
        <meta-data android:name="bootType" android:value="restart"/>
        <meta-data android:name="sendToBack" android:value="true"/>
    </receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge it is not possible to arrive at the same behavior as with the gps Popup.
There is also no way of knowing if a user turned on autostart for your APP or not.
So I think the only thing you can to is to ask the user to turn on autostart for your app as you are already doing. Ask this for example once on apps first open and then store a value in shared preferences to prevent that popup every time the app starts the next time.